# Leaflet polygon fillColor argument always produces error

Tags: r, gis, r-leaflet

I've been trying to produce a basic leaflet map of low income benefits in australia.

```
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(downloader)
library(dplyr)
library(RColorBrewer)

url <- "https://data.gov.au/dataset/0ed76b6e-4f6e-4cc6-9f95-0b4e3729dc69/resource/b50acd1e-5c0d-4260-8ebd-997fe97b7adb/download/asgs2017.gpkg"

download(url, dest="dataset2017.gpkg", mode="wb") 
lga_data <- st_read("dataset2017.gpkg",layer = "local_government_area_2017")
unlink("dataset2017.gpkg")

dss_payments <- read.csv("https://data.gov.au/data/dataset/8dc2eaa3-e052-43a4-806b-91ca9306c346/resource/1cdccd05-80cd-46db-8d5a-933b4a4d129f/download/dss-demographics-march-2021-lga-csv-geo-au.csv") %>%
        mutate(LGA_Code_2020 = as.character(LGA_Code_2020))

df <- lga_data %>%
        select(LGA_CODE_2017,LGA_NAME_2017) %>%
        mutate(LGA_CODE_2017 = as.character(LGA_CODE_2017))%>%
        left_join(dss_payments, by = c("LGA_CODE_2017"="LGA_Code_2020")) %>%
        filter(!is.na(LGA_name_2020))

rm(list = c(dss_payments,lga_data))

pal <- colorBin("PuRd", domain = df$Low.Income.Card, bins = seq(from=0,to=5000,by=500))

m <- leaflet() %>%
        #addProviderTiles("CartoDB.DarkMatter") %>%
        leaflet::addPolygons(data=st_sfc(df$shape)
                             ,weight=1
                             ,opacity=1
                             ,color="white"
                             ,dashArray = "3"
                             ,fillColor = ~pal(Low.Income.Card)
                             )
m
```

If i run it all **except** fillColor it works perfectly, but with fillColor I get a cryptic and difficult to interpret error message:

> Error in UseMethod("metaData") : no applicable method for 'metaData' applied to an object of class "c('sfc_MULTIPOLYGON', 'sfc')"

Im struggling to find many usable resources online, has anyone run into this issue before? Or can work out what the issue is?
Thanks!

Comment: I think it will be because you've only supplied one column as the data `st_sfc(df$shape)`.

Comment: I was wondering if you ever resolved this issue? I am running into the same one.